# Translation of "running example"

Tags: traduction, anglais

When trying to translate *running example* into French, a friend suggested *exemple filet*, but I could not find a single instance of this usage. I did find however *exemple fil rouge* in a few websites.

I'd prefer to find a more authoritative source for this usage, or a more widely used translation. Apparently, most writers just resort to *exemple* (without further characterizing it) or to a lengthy description (*l'exemple qui sera utilisé au long du texte...*).

Any suggestions/references?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by a 'running example'. Seems to be related to programming, is it?

Comment: About the suggestion *exemple filet*, I suspect a misunderstanding. *A running metaphor* is translated as *une métaphore filée*. Could it be that someone tried to apply the same logic with *running example*, and told it to you orally only ? In any case, this expression is unknown in french.

Answer (score 5):

- *exemple filet* seems strange to me, I'd not have understood it without a clear context allowing to understand the meaning.
- *exemple fil rouge* should be understandable but I'd not use the expression as is.  I'd use something like "l'exemple qui nous servira de fil rouge" or "l'exemple qui suit, fil rouge de ce document, ..." for the introduction and "reprenons notre fil rouge" or "reprenons notre exemple" but not "reprenons notre exemple fil rouge" when going back to it.

Answer (score 2):

L'exemple peut être introduit comme suit dans une note ou une documentation :

> *L'exemple de référence* que nous utiliserons par la suite,

ou comme suit, dans un écrit didactique avec une orientation technique ou logique :

> *L'exemple référent* pour cet exposé.

On pourra par la suite utiliser :

- *L'exemple en référence*, pour le rappeler
- *L'exemple ci-dessus*, pour un rappel dans un exposé,
- *L'exemple ci-devant* avec la même signification que l'exemple *ci-dessus*, mais en langage soutenu, selon le contexte, il peut être connoté ironique.
- *L'exemple en cours* qui convient aussi très bien dans de nombreux cas.

---

*L'exemple en cours***e**  donné par [Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=running%20example) pour *Course example* est à PROSCRIRE car c'est une traduction automatique.
Traduire l'anglais *course* par le mot français *course* (au lieu de *cours*) amène un contre-sens : *être en course*, c'est être en concurrence ou en déplacement pour gagner du temps, alors qu'une affaire *en cours* suit *le cours* des choses, est dans le temps qui s'écoule.
De même pour le [Reverso](http://www.reverso.net/translationresults.aspx?lang=FR&direction=anglais-francais) : *Course(Direction) d'exemple*.

Comment: +1 pour votre différenciation de cours (nm) vs course (nf).